# How can I cleanly exit an npm server test for CI?

Tags: node.js, bash, server, travis-ci

I've been developing a node based server that I want to have tested on Travis-ci, the problem is the only thing I want to test now is if the server has any errors on *start*

(It's just a backend for serving an API; all it does on start is serve out of a port).

If it starts fine, I don't want it to run forever on the CI's VM. I've tried having the *test* script in my package.json point to a bash script that uses `kill` with the PID but that doesn't exit cleanly to pass Travis's build.

Long story short, what should I write to have my test run `npm start` for a couple of seconds and then close node cleanly if there are no errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a wrapper around your server that you run as your test in which you can exit after x amount of seconds or if an error occurs. Something like this:

```
require('./myserver') // i asume this starts your server
setTimeout(() => process.exit(0), 5000) // exits with 0 exit code after 5 seconds
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log(err)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Comment: Excellent, I was able to integrate the timeout and error check into my existing server! Thanks~